# Need monthly status of each member ID and a flag if they are registered or not

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have two tables where each table has two rows in common (ID and Date). I want to get all the rows from Table 1 and then add another column for a flag showing if there was appointment or not. I have tried to use left join but didn't work.

Table 1

```
ID, DateYM, Status
1,  2021-01-01, On
1,  2021-02-01, On
1,  2021-03-01, Off
1,  2021-04-01, On
1,  2021-05-01, On
1,  2021-06-01, On
2,  2021-01-01, Off
2,  2021-02-01, On
2,  2021-03-01, Off
2,  2021-04-01, On
2,  2021-05-01, On
2,  2021-06-01, On
3,  2021-01-01, On
3,  2021-02-01, Off
3,  2021-03-01, On
3,  2021-04-01, On
3,  2021-05-01, On
3,  2021-06-01, On
```

Table 2

```
ID, Appt_date, Appointment
1,  2021-01-12, Registered
1,  2021-04-14, Registered
1,  2021-05-13, Registered
2,  2021-02-12, Registered
2,  2021-04-17, Registered
2,  2021-05-15, Registered
2,  2021-06-12, Registered
3,  2021-03-19, Registered
3,  2021-06-10, Registered
```

Expected result table:

```
ID, DateYM, Status, Appointment
1,  2021-01-01, On, Yes
1,  2021-02-01, On, No
1,  2021-03-01, Off, No
1,  2021-04-01, On, Yes
1,  2021-05-01, On, Yes
1,  2021-06-01, On, No
2,  2021-01-01, Off, NO
2,  2021-02-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-03-01, Off, No
2,  2021-04-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-05-01, On, Yes
2,  2021-06-01, On, Yes
3,  2021-01-01, On, No
3,  2021-02-01, Off, No
3,  2021-03-01, On, Yes
3,  2021-04-01, On, No
3,  2021-05-01, On, No
3,  2021-06-01, On, Yes
```

Query that I used for mysql:

```
    SELECT t1.ID,
         t1.DateYM,
         t1.Status,
         (CASE WHEN t2.Appointment = 'Registered' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Appointment
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 
           ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
          and t1.DateYM = t2.Appt_date
    ORDER BY t1.YYMM
```

For a given ID, I am getting multiple rows for the same month when I left join instead to having just 6 rows per ID. How do I get unique rows for each month that tells me just yes or no without multiple rows for the same month?

Comment: Where is your code that uses `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I tried using GROUP BY as well but didn't post that query here. I was just grouping by 1,2,3,4

Comment: Add your best attempt of the desired script to your question (using [Edit]) and explain how it falls short of your goal.

Comment: As per your given when status value of table1 is ON then a row exists in table2 for corresponding month. So why need table2 for joining.

Comment: Regardless of whatever the status is, there is a requirement to have the appointment flag from table2.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Getting just 1 row is a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can efficiently get your desired results not using a join but using `exists`.

Note your dates do not align and from your expected results you are only checking the month which seems odd but only you know your desired logic.

```
select *, 
  case when exists (
        select * from t2 
        where t1.id=t2.id 
        and date_format(t1.dateym, "%Y-%m") = date_format(t2.appt_date, "%Y-%m") 
        and t2.appointment='Registered'
    ) then 'Yes' else 'No' end Appointment 
from t1
```

[Example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=384378ebce4c9c09ab386a420fb45c15)

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If there is one more column in Table 2 and I want to include that column in my final output, what would be the best approach to do that? I tried join the table but I am getting extra row of what expected. 

Query:
select *, state,
  case when exists (
  select * from t2 
  where t1.id=t2.id 
  and date_format(t1.dateym, "%Y-%m") = date_format(t2.appt_date, "%Y-%m") and t2.appointment='Registered') then 'Yes' else 'No' end Appointment 
from t1
join t2 on t1.id=t2.id

Answer (score 0):

Convert YYYY-MM-DD to YYYY-MM of both table date field and then JOIN this two converted column along with ID.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT t1.ID
     , t1.DateYM
     , t1.Status
     , (CASE WHEN t2.Appointment = 'Registered' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Appointment
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
       and DATE_FORMAT(t1.DateYM, "%Y-%m") = DATE_FORMAT(t2.Appt_date, "%Y-%m")
ORDER BY t1.ID, t1.DateYM
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=849cb348f211413ca984d557fdb44ce1

Comment: @Tina please check this query.

Answer (score 0):

You have a flaw.

```
LEFT JOIN Table2 [...] t1.DateYM = t2.Appt_date
```

Is not working.
Because you have different Values in t1 and t2.
Eg. for id 1 t1.dateym = 2021-01-01 and t2.appt_date = 2021-01-12
You cannot join on that, its always false.

You need to join on substring with like.

```
t2.appt_date LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING(t1.dateym,1,7),'%')
```

Which results in "2021-01-12" like "2021-01%".

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf8350/8)

Edit: Rahuls answer is probably faster as it does not involve `like`